# Matlab Code and Mathematica Code both identical with different results

Tags: differential-equations, matlab

I have spent so much time working around with this code to give the same identical answer as the code I have written before over Matlab. 
I am just trying to switch towards using Mathematica in my research and would like to get the same result.

I think the problem is related to the NDsolve parameters or method of integration. Sometimes working with the initial conditions helps gets the required behavior. I just don't know!

Followed the Mathematica code and the expected result from Matlab.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"] (*Remove all global variables*)
alpha1 = 0.02;
gamma = 2.21276*^5; (*1.7580859`*^11 2*Pi*27.99*^9 \
1/(T.S)*)(*2.21276*^5   m/(A.S)*)
gammaLLG = (gamma)/(1 + alpha1^2) ;

Ki0 = 1.0056364*^-3;
tFL = 1.1*^-9;
tox = 1.1*^-9;
mu0 = 4*Pi*1*^-7;
Ms0 = 1.2*^6;
etaVCMA = 37*^-15;
V = 1.2;


Ms0 = 1.2*^6;
Nx = 0.0045;
Ny = 0.0152;
Nz = 0.9803;

HDem = Ms0*{Nx, Ny, Nz}*{Sin[M1[t]]*Cos[M2[t]], Sin[M1[t]]*Sin[M2[t]],
     Cos[M1[t]]};
Hexternal = {-100*1000/(4*Pi), 0, 0}; 
Hkp = {0, 0, 
    2*Ki0/(tFL*mu0*Ms0) - 2*etaVCMA*V/(tFL*mu0*Ms0*tox)} *{Sin[M1[t]]*
     Cos[M2[t]], Sin[M1[t]]*Sin[M2[t]], Cos[M1[t]]};


H = Hexternal - HDem + Hkp;

tstart = 0;
tend = 10*^-9;

initial1 = {M1[0] == 0.01};
initial2 = {M2[0] == 0.01};

Spherical = {{Cos[M1[t]]*Cos[M2[t]], 
    Cos[M1[t]]*Sin[M2[t]], -Sin[M1[t]]}, {-Sin[M2[t]], Cos[M2[t]], 0}};
SphericalH = Spherical.H;
LLG = {{alpha1, 1}, {-1/Sin[M1[t]], alpha1/Sin[M1[t]]}};
stat = gammaLLG*(LLG.SphericalH);
eq = {M1'[t] == stat[[1]]};
eq2 = {M2'[t] == stat[[2]]};
eqns2 = Join[eq, eq2, initial1, initial2];
xxxa2 = Simplify[eqns2]


sol2 = NDSolve[xxxa2, {M1[t], M2[t]}, {t, tstart, tend}, 
   StartingStepSize -> 1/10000, 
   Method -> {"FixedStep", Method -> "ExplicitEuler"}];

{M1[t], M2[t]} = {M1[t], M2[t]} /. sol2[[1]];

x2 = Sin[M1[t]]*Cos[M2[t]];
Plot[x2, {t, tstart, tend}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
y2 = Sin[M1[t]]*Sin[M2[t]];
Plot[y2, {t, tstart, tend}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]

z2 = Cos[M1[t]];
Plot[z2, {t, tstart, tend}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]

ParametricPlot3D[{x2, y2, z2}, {t, tstart, tend}, PlotRange -> 1, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, AxesLabel -> {X, Y, Z}]
```

I am not sure if you can recommend me different NDsolve method that helps me get the required behavior.

I don't exclude the idea that maybe something wrong with my Mathematica code but I tried hard to keep booth codes exactly similar.

The expected output should be like this I used ode45 in Matlab as a command to solve the differential equations.

[image]

Comment: If you want to try to reproduce the result of `ode45()` in *Mathematica*, see [this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveExplicitRungeKutta.html#451488706). Otherwise, I would tell you to try adding the setting `Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"` in `NDSolve[]`, because your choice to use Euler's method in `NDSolve[]` is quite poor.

Comment: "I think the problem is related to the NDsolve parameters or method of integration. " I don't think so. The initial value problem (IVP) solver is quite robust, and it should always be the last thing to check. Better to double check if the equation system and initial conditions are the same as those in your matlab code. Also, it's important to make sure you've handled the unit of parameters correctly.

Comment: @AQoutb Maybe you want to post also your _Matlab_ code? That might help to find a translation error if there is any. But I have also to say that ` Method -> {"FixedStep", Method -> "ExplicitEuler"}` basically asks for trouble. Rule of thumb: If you do not know which particular method to use, let _Mathematica_ decide.

Comment: To be blunt, ode45 is a six-stage fifth-order Runge-Kutta method. There's something about Dormand and Prince rather than Fehlberg, also. Here's a [reference](https://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2014/05/26/ordinary-differential-equation-solvers-ode23-and-ode45/).

Comment: @J.M.'stechnicaldifficulties I guess you are right. Once I deleted the methods and let NDsolve do its work and choose its method. it works fine. 
Actually there was something else wrong with the code that I had to work on separately. Do you recommend me to delete this question or leave it to others?!

Comment: @CATrevillian, yes, there are a lot of different 4(5) embedded RK methods; Dormand-Prince (what MATLAB's `ode45()` uses) is one, Fehlberg's original is another, and the version used internally by *Mathematica* through `Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", "DifferenceOrder" -> 5}` is yet another.

Comment: A Qoutb, if you think you now understand enough to answer your own question, please write an answer. Then, other people can check your answer to see if you got it properly.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a problem of precision. There are very high prefactors to Sin,Cos and very low t. With rationalization of   `xxxa2 = Simplify[eqns2 // Rationalize[#, 0] &]` it works fine.

```
xxxa2 = Simplify[eqns2 // Rationalize[#, 0] &]

sol2 = NDSolve[xxxa2, {M1, M2}, {t, tstart, tend}]

x2 = Sin[M1[t]]*Cos[M2[t]] /. sol2[[1]];
y2 = Sin[M1[t]]*Sin[M2[t]] /. sol2[[1]];
z2 = Cos[M1[t]] /. sol2[[1]];
Plot[{x2, y2, z2}, {t, tstart, tend}, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Green}]
```

[image]

```
ParametricPlot3D[{x2, y2, z2}, {t, tstart, tend}, PlotRange -> 1, 
    BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, AxesLabel -> {X, Y, Z}]
```

[image]

**Edit**  (test of diffequation result)

With higher working precision error is about 1 per cent (x2,y2,z2 are the same).

```
sol3 = NDSolve[xxxa2, {M1, M2}, {t, tstart, tend}, MaxSteps -> 10^7, 
  StartingStepSize -> 10^-15, MaxStepSize -> 10^-13, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 50]

Plot[xxxa2[[1, 1]] - xxxa2[[1, 2]] /. First@sol3, {t, tstart, tend}]
```

[image]

Comment: `Rationalize[#, 0] &` is not necessary. Once options of `NDSolve` in OP's code are removed, this result will be obtained.